# Angular/Ionic File object constructor outputs malformed instance

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

On a new Angular 4 project is possible to create a simple text File object from its constructor:

```
const textfile = new File (['abcd'], 'text.txt')
console.log(textfile)
```

inspecting the console output (VSCode console) shows the expected result:

```
File(13) {name: "text.txt", lastModified: 1520684955392, lastModifiedDate: Sat Mar 10 2018 13:29:15 GMT+0100 (Standard romance time…, webkitRelativePath: "", size: 13, …}
    lastModified:1520684955392
    lastModifiedDate:Sat Mar 10 2018 13:29:15 GMT+0100 {}
    name:"text.txt"
    size:13
    type:"text/plain"
    webkitRelativePath:""
    __proto__:File {name: <accessor>, lastModified: <accessor>, lastModifiedDate: <accessor>, …}
```

This exact line of code on a new blank Ionic 3 project outputs a misplaced or wrong properties instance of File interface ("name" is an Array holding text content, there's no "name" property, "localURL" contains the file name, "start" "size" and "end" properties are 0, ...).

```
File {name: Array(1), localURL: "text.txt", type: null, lastModified: null, lastModifiedDate: null, …}
end:0
lastModified:null
lastModifiedDate:null
localURL:"text.txt"
name:Array(1) ["text"]
size:0
start:0
type:null
__proto__:Object {slice: , constructor: }
```

Tried to simplify my question as much as I could, tested on diferent computers and checked Angular and Ionic stable versions. I have served this project to the local browser to avoid device or emulator interference.

I wonder if this is a by-design behavior, a bug on Ionic's Angular implementation or a wrong use of this feature.

EDIT:

Answering Reed comment:

Many answers suggested to bypass Ionic to solve **my issue** and write the code on plain Angular. Ionic's documentation and resources didn't give any working answer at that time.

Ionic was just another layer of complexity (JS -> TS -> Angular -> cordova/capacitor -> Ionic) over a too heavy stack.

So the solution to **this issue and for my needs** (YMMV) was removing Ionic from my stack and go as low as I've been able.

You can read more on the comments of this post.

Answer (score 1):

**Following way worked for me in Android as well**

```
blobToFileConverison() {
   this.blobToFileConverison(**base64**, 'Filename.xml').then(
   (file: File) => {
      const deltaObj: FormData = new FormData();
      deltaObj.append('file', file, 'Filename.xml');

      /***
        Further code goes here
      **/
   })
}  

async blobToFileConverison(dataUrl: string, fileName: string): Promise<File> {
   const res: Response = await fetch(dataUrl);
   const blob: Blob = await res.blob();
   return this.blobToFile(blob, fileName, new Date());
}

blobToFile(theBlob: Blob, fileName: string, dateGenerated: Date): File {
    const b: any = theBlob;
    //A Blob() is almost a File() - it's just missing the two properties below which we will add
    b.lastModifiedDate = dateGenerated;
    b.name = fileName;

    //Cast to a File() type
    return <File>b;
}
```

It may help someone!

Answer (score 0):

Try following code -

```
var fileContent = [];
var blob = new Blob(['abcd'], { type: 'text/plain' });
fileContent.push(blob);  
const textfile = new File (fileContent, 'text.txt', {
  type: 'text/plain',
})
console.log(textfile);
```

Comment: Oh yes. I did it but not included. No chance. But If you had tried you did noticed it doesn't work.

Comment: @JosepAlacid For me it is working fine when I do ionic serve in browser. Is this problem specific to particular browser or device.

Comment: Working on Android, same error on iPhone... This is crazy!!